# Working with the UI design of a ListView custom row (Android)

Tags: android, listview, user-interface

I made a custom row layout xml file for a ListView so I could design each row to look how I want, but I'm having trouble actually designing the UI in this xml file. I'm trying to make the the activity ultimately look like this:

[image]

As you can see there is a listView with rows, each consisting of a game with a textView as a title, two buttons, and an imageView as the background. I've been doing a lot of research through Google's UI documentation but I can't figure out how to get the elements to appear on top of each other like this while have the row scale perfectly to different screen sizes. The furthest I've gotten is using a FrameLayout to place the different views on top of each other, but from here I cannot place the views in the correct position relative to each other. Any advice on how to do this or where I can find out how to do this?

XML so far (terrible I know):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gameImageID"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/overwatch" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gameNameID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnJoinLobby"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="myClickHandlerJoin"
        android:text="Join Lobby"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCreateLobby"
        android:layout_width="102dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="myClickHandlerCreate"
        android:text="Create Lobby"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/gameNameID" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show us your code. thats a very easy design

Comment: @DroiDev just added the xml for custom row

Comment: Share your code and image of what it looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure that is no problem. Just use weight to handle spacing and you don't need the frame layout just use relative as a root.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gameImageID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/overwatch" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gameNameID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnJoinLobby"
                    android:layout_width="102dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="myClickHandlerJoin"
                    android:text="Join Lobby"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnCreateLobby"
                    android:layout_width="102dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="myClickHandlerCreate"
                    android:text="Create Lobby"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You could also just use two nested Relative Layouts with gravity bottom left and bottom right and hold your buttons in there and align buttons to right with margins from side. Also don't use the "endOF" aligning as that will force a left alignment and make larger gaps on the right side of the screen even if you make it look good for one phone it will look bad on another. Aesthetics matter.

Or you could just float your buttons to the bottom left and bottom right with margins from side and make both set to match_parent so they fill the space but use padding to shrink the button look inside the space, but this can get messy. So I prefer the implementation above although some people won't like the extra layouts. It's just a matter of opinion though as the performance diff of using extra nested layouts is so tiny that no one can actually argue performance with a straight face haha.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="340dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:background="@drawable/overwatch" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/gameNameID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnJoinLobby"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="myClickHandlerJoin"
    android:text="Join Lobby"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCreateLobby"
    android:layout_width="102dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="myClickHandlerCreate"
    android:text="Create Lobby"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnJoinLobby" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Try this. And let me know if that helps.